# How to convert print output to pyspark dataframe (no pandas allowed)

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

The usual code

```
print((sparkdf.count(), len(sparkdf.columns)))
```

Since I using HDFS system that fully on HDFS, no pandas allowed, The output I need

```
|-------|-------|
|row    |columns|
|-------|-------|
|1500   |    22 |
|-------|-------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `spark.createDataFrame` and pass the values as a list of tuple:

```
spark.createDataFrame([(sparkdf.count(), len(sparkdf.columns))], schema=['rows', 'columns'])
```